# Handling browser history with React-Redux

Tags: browser-history, react-redux

We are using React-Redux in your application. The problem is that we want to do undo and redo Redux state based on user navigation from browser buttons. Assume user is in page A and user browses couple of other pages and then he navigates to page A, for instance. Now If user presses back button in the browser, he'll go back to page A but here we want to have the previous instance of state which application had when user the page A.

Is there a centralized approach to solve this problem that doesn't need to handle the state manipulation manually.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is a default behavior of React-Redux. If you are not trying to dispatch some actions, which manipulates specific component's state, when a route changes, it should persist its old state, without any additional functionality.

So my guess is that you are dispatching some actions when new route loads the component. How it could be dealt with this (e.g not to fetch resources from rest API once it existed, which finally caused to manipulate component) is here: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/src/actions/index.js#L35

```
const shouldFetchPosts = (state, reddit) => {
  const posts = state.postsByReddit[reddit]
  if (!posts) {
    return true
  }
  if (posts.isFetching) {
    return false
  }
  return posts.didInvalidate
}

export const fetchPostsIfNeeded = reddit => (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), reddit)) {
    return dispatch(fetchPosts(reddit))
  }
}
```

So what this is doing is that it won't pass a new data into component once route changes if it already exists, so the old data/state stays there. You can abstract this functions more to make it easily reusable for all the other components.